# VFIO nvidia code 43 despite hiding virtual machine

Tags: nvidia, kvm-virtualization, 21.04

I am using Ubuntu 21.04.
I have a AMD Radeon RX550 and an Nvidia GTX 1050Ti

I am trying to set up VFIO passthrough for the nvidia card in a Windows VM.
Windows reports error code 43 on the nvidia card in device manager after installing the nvidia drivers on the virtual machine and i'm stuck with 800x600 in the VM.

The primary card is the AMD (ie, the one that shows the BIOS post when turning on the physical machine)
I have removed the nvidia driver, blacklisted both nvidia and nouveau
/etc/modprobe.d/nvidea-graphics-drivers.conf

```
blacklist nvidia
blacklist nouveau
```

in grub I am attaching VFIO-PCI to the nvidea card like so

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="intel_iommu=on kvm.ignore_msrs=1 vfio-pci.ids=10de:1c82,10de:0fb9 vfio_iommu_type1.allow_unsafe_interrupts=1 video=vesafb:off video=efifb:off"
```

I have tried following these instructions to resolve code 43
https://mathiashueber.com/fighting-error-43-nvidia-gpu-virtual-machine/

My virtual machine configuration:

```
<domain type="kvm">
  <name>win10</name>
  <uuid>59656775-5930-11df-bbda-8577d84ed8d3</uuid>
  <metadata>
    <libosinfo:libosinfo xmlns:libosinfo="http://libosinfo.org/xmlns/libvirt/domain/1.0">
      <libosinfo:os id="http://microsoft.com/win/10"/>
    </libosinfo:libosinfo>
  </metadata>
  <memory unit="KiB">8388608</memory>
  <currentMemory unit="KiB">8388608</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement="static">2</vcpu>
  <os>
    <type arch="x86_64" machine="pc-q35-5.2">hvm</type>
    <loader readonly="yes" secure="yes" type="pflash">/usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_CODE_4M.secboot.fd</loader>
    <nvram>/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/nvram/win10_VARS.fd</nvram>
    <bootmenu enable="no"/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <hyperv>
      <relaxed state="on"/>
      <vapic state="on"/>
      <spinlocks state="on" retries="8191"/>
      <vendor_id state="on" value="1234567890ab"/>
    </hyperv>
    <kvm>
      <hidden state="on"/>
    </kvm>
    <vmport state="off"/>
    <smm state="on"/>
    <ioapic driver="kvm"/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode="host-passthrough" check="none" migratable="on">
    <feature policy="disable" name="hypervisor"/>
  </cpu>
  <clock offset="localtime">
    <timer name="rtc" tickpolicy="catchup"/>
    <timer name="pit" tickpolicy="delay"/>
    <timer name="hpet" present="no"/>
    <timer name="hypervclock" present="no"/>
  </clock>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>destroy</on_crash>
  <pm>
    <suspend-to-mem enabled="no"/>
    <suspend-to-disk enabled="no"/>
  </pm>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64</emulator>
    <disk type="file" device="cdrom">
      <driver name="qemu" type="raw"/>
      <source file="/home/maria/Downloads/virtio-win-0.1.185.iso"/>
      <target dev="sdb" bus="sata"/>
      <readonly/>
      <boot order="1"/>
      <address type="drive" controller="0" bus="0" target="0" unit="1"/>
    </disk>
    <disk type="file" device="disk">
      <driver name="qemu" type="qcow2"/>
      <source file="/home/maria/virtual_machines/windows10.qcow2"/>
      <target dev="sdc" bus="sata"/>
      <boot order="2"/>
      <address type="drive" controller="0" bus="0" target="0" unit="2"/>
    </disk>
    <controller type="usb" index="0" model="qemu-xhci" ports="15">
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x02" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="sata" index="0">
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x1f" function="0x2"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="0" model="pcie-root"/>
    <controller type="pci" index="1" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="1" port="0x10"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x0" multifunction="on"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="2" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="2" port="0x11"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x1"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="3" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="3" port="0x12"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x2"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="4" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="4" port="0x13"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x3"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="5" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="5" port="0x14"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x4"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="6" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="6" port="0x15"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x5"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="7" model="pcie-to-pci-bridge">
      <model name="pcie-pci-bridge"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x05" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="8" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="8" port="0x16"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x6"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="9" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="9" port="0x8"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x01" function="0x0" multifunction="on"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="10" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="10" port="0x9"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x01" function="0x1"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="11" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="11" port="0xa"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x01" function="0x2"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="12" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="12" port="0xb"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x01" function="0x3"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="13" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="13" port="0xc"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x01" function="0x4"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="14" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="14" port="0xd"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x01" function="0x5"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="15" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="15" port="0xe"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x01" function="0x6"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="16" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="16" port="0xf"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x01" function="0x7"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="17" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="17" port="0x17"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x02" function="0x7"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="18" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="18" port="0x18"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x03" function="0x0" multifunction="on"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="19" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="19" port="0x19"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x03" function="0x1"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="20" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="20" port="0x1a"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x03" function="0x2"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="21" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="21" port="0x1b"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x03" function="0x3"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="22" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="22" port="0x1c"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x03" function="0x4"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="23" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="23" port="0x1d"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x03" function="0x5"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="pci" index="24" model="pcie-root-port">
      <model name="pcie-root-port"/>
      <target chassis="24" port="0x1e"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x03" function="0x6"/>
    </controller>
    <controller type="virtio-serial" index="0">
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x03" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
    </controller>
    <interface type="network">
      <mac address="52:54:00:70:14:a4"/>
      <source network="default"/>
      <model type="virtio"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x01" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
    </interface>
    <serial type="pty">
      <target type="isa-serial" port="0">
        <model name="isa-serial"/>
      </target>
    </serial>
    <console type="pty">
      <target type="serial" port="0"/>
    </console>
    <channel type="spicevmc">
      <target type="virtio" name="com.redhat.spice.0"/>
      <address type="virtio-serial" controller="0" bus="0" port="1"/>
    </channel>
    <input type="tablet" bus="usb">
      <address type="usb" bus="0" port="1"/>
    </input>
    <input type="mouse" bus="ps2"/>
    <input type="keyboard" bus="ps2"/>
    <graphics type="spice" autoport="yes">
      <listen type="address"/>
      <image compression="off"/>
    </graphics>
    <sound model="ich9">
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x1b" function="0x0"/>
    </sound>
    <video>
      <model type="none"/>
    </video>
    <hostdev mode="subsystem" type="usb" managed="yes">
      <source>
        <vendor id="0x0461"/>
        <product id="0x4e04"/>
      </source>
      <address type="usb" bus="0" port="4"/>
    </hostdev>
    <hostdev mode="subsystem" type="usb" managed="yes">
      <source>
        <vendor id="0x093a"/>
        <product id="0x2510"/>
      </source>
      <address type="usb" bus="0" port="5"/>
    </hostdev>
    <hostdev mode="subsystem" type="pci" managed="yes">
      <source>
        <address domain="0x0000" bus="0x18" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
      </source>
      <rom file="/usr/share/ovmf/GP107.bin"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x06" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
    </hostdev>
    <hostdev mode="subsystem" type="pci" managed="yes">
      <source>
        <address domain="0x0000" bus="0x18" slot="0x00" function="0x1"/>
      </source>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x08" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
    </hostdev>
    <redirdev bus="usb" type="spicevmc">
      <address type="usb" bus="0" port="2"/>
    </redirdev>
    <redirdev bus="usb" type="spicevmc">
      <address type="usb" bus="0" port="3"/>
    </redirdev>
    <memballoon model="virtio">
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x04" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
    </memballoon>
    <shmem name="looking-glass">
      <model type="ivshmem-plain"/>
      <size unit="M">32</size>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x07" slot="0x01" function="0x0"/>
    </shmem>
  </devices>
</domain>
```

as you can see I have hidden the virtual machine and in Windows 10 task manager under processor it displays as if it's not a virtual machine.

My IOMMU groups are as follows

```
IOMMU Group 0 00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor DMI [8086:d130] (rev 11)
IOMMU Group 1 00:03.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Core Processor PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:d138] (rev 11)
IOMMU Group 2 00:08.0 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Core Processor System Management Registers [8086:d155] (rev 11)
IOMMU Group 3 00:08.1 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Core Processor Semaphore and Scratchpad Registers [8086:d156] (rev 11)
IOMMU Group 4 00:08.2 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Core Processor System Control and Status Registers [8086:d157] (rev 11)
IOMMU Group 5 00:08.3 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Core Processor Miscellaneous Registers [8086:d158] (rev 11)
IOMMU Group 6 00:10.0 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link [8086:d150] (rev 11)
IOMMU Group 6 00:10.1 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Routing and Protocol Registers [8086:d151] (rev 11)
IOMMU Group 7 00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller [8086:3b64] (rev 06)
IOMMU Group 7 00:16.3 Serial controller [0700]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset KT Controller [8086:3b67] (rev 06)
IOMMU Group 8 00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82578DM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:10ef] (rev 05)
IOMMU Group 9 00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller [8086:3b3c] (rev 05)
IOMMU Group 10 00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio [8086:3b56] (rev 05)
IOMMU Group 11 00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:3b42] (rev 05)
IOMMU Group 12 00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 5 [8086:3b4a] (rev 05)
IOMMU Group 13 00:1c.6 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 7 [8086:3b4e] (rev 05)
IOMMU Group 14 00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller [8086:3b34] (rev 05)
IOMMU Group 15 00:1e.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge [8086:244e] (rev a5)
IOMMU Group 16 00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation 3450 Chipset LPC Interface Controller [8086:3b16] (rev 05)
IOMMU Group 16 00:1f.2 RAID bus controller [0104]: Intel Corporation SATA Controller [RAID mode] [8086:2822] (rev 05)
IOMMU Group 17 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Baffin [Radeon RX 550 640SP / RX 560/560X] [1002:67ff] (rev ff)
IOMMU Group 17 01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Baffin HDMI/DP Audio [Radeon RX 550 640SP / RX 560/560X] [1002:aae0]
IOMMU Group 18 18:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti] [10de:1c82] (rev a1)
IOMMU Group 18 18:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GP107GL High Definition Audio Controller [10de:0fb9] (rev a1)
IOMMU Group 19 3f:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-Core Registers [8086:2c50] (rev 04)
IOMMU Group 19 3f:00.1 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder [8086:2c81] (rev 04)
IOMMU Group 20 3f:02.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 [8086:2c90] (rev 04)
IOMMU Group 20 3f:02.1 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Physical 0 [8086:2c91] (rev 04)
IOMMU Group 21 3f:03.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller [8086:2c98] (rev 04)
IOMMU Group 21 3f:03.1 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Target Address Decoder [8086:2c99] (rev 04)
IOMMU Group 21 3f:03.2 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Test Registers [8086:2c9a] (rev 04)
IOMMU Group 21 3f:03.4 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Test Registers [8086:2c9c] (rev 04)
IOMMU Group 22 3f:04.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0 Control Registers [8086:2ca0] (rev 04)
IOMMU Group 22 3f:04.1 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0 Address Registers [8086:2ca1] (rev 04)
IOMMU Group 22 3f:04.2 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0 Rank Registers [8086:2ca2] (rev 04)
IOMMU Group 22 3f:04.3 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Channel 0 Thermal Control Registers [8086:2ca3] (rev 04)
IOMMU Group 23 3f:05.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1 Control Registers [8086:2ca8] (rev 04)
IOMMU Group 23 3f:05.1 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1 Address Registers [8086:2ca9] (rev 04)
IOMMU Group 23 3f:05.2 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1 Rank Registers [8086:2caa] (rev 04)
IOMMU Group 23 3f:05.3 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Memory Controller Channel 1 Thermal Control Registers [8086:2cab] (rev 04)
```

as you can see every device has it's own IOMMU group (this is a server motherboard).

There are no errors from VFIO in dmesg.
I am at a loss as how to resolve this, any help would be appreciated.